# Why is the return value of a model method in Django not showing up to the template?

Tags: python, django, function, search, methods

I have this function inside my model that is not appearing when I try to run the server. I think I am accessing the method correctly but when I tried writing print("ENTER") inside the total_balance() function, nothing showed up which makes me think that it's not even entering the method at all. Oddly, the function works if I take out the search functionality.

model.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def total_balance():
        transaction_list = Transaction.objects.filter(user=User)
        total_balance_amount = 0
        for transaction in transaction_list:
            if transaction.category=='Income':
                total_balance_amount += transaction.amount
            elif transaction.category=='Expense':
                total_balance_amount -= transaction.amount
        return total_balance_amount
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):

    if request.method == 'GET':

        query = request.GET.get('q')

        if query and query!="":
            results = Transaction.objects.filter(Q(tag__icontains=query))
        else:
            results = Transaction.objects.all()

        transactions = {
            'transactions' : results,
        }

        profile = {
            'profile' : Profile.objects.all()
        }
        return render(request, 'users/profile.html', transactions, profile)
```

template.py

```
<h5 class="card-title">Total Balance</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">₱{{ profile.total_balance }}</p>
```

Can someone please help me identify the reason this is not working and how I might be able to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least four things wrong here.

Firstly, for some reason you are passing two separate dictionaries to `render`. That doesn't work; you need a single dictionary with multiple entries.

```
    context = {
        'transactions' : results,
        'profile' : Profile.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context )
```

Secondly, `profile` - despite the singular name - is a queryset of *all* profiles. You would need to iterate through it in your template:

```
{% for prof in profile %}
    <p class="card-text">₱{{ prof.total_balance }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Ideally, you would use a more appropriate name for the context variable, ie `profiles`.

Next, your `total_balance` method itself has two issues. Firstly, any method in Python needs to take the `self` parameter. And secondly, you need to use that parameter to access the *value* of the `user` field, not the class User. So:

```
def total_balance(self):
    transaction_list = Transaction.objects.filter(user=self.user)
```

although note that that second line could be more easily written:

```
    transaction_list = self.user.transaction_set.all()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Would User not work if I am importing 'from django.contrib.auth.models import User'?

Comment: No, why should it? That's a class. It makes no sense to use it there. You want the value of the user field on the current instance of Profile.